# webpack как включить в сборку папку которая находится в node_modules

Tags: javascript, frontend, webpack, ecmascript-6

В папке node_modules находится папка с нужными мне исходниками. Исходники этой папки должны собираться с текущей сборкой проекта. Нужно включить эту папку в текущую сборку проекта, а так же выполнить транспиляцию с помощью babel (es6). Кто такое проделывал поделитесь знаниями пожалуйста.

webpack версии 2.6.1